# Postman API Invalid Content-Type Header

Tags: rest, postman, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to test and API call for the Smartsheet API in Postman, but I keep receiving the same error. Even though I am defining the correct Content-Type as per the API documentation, the response I get is the **error 1124**, which is an **invalid content-type header**. I haven't been able to figure out exactly what is causing the issue. I have tried typing the header in the address and in the header tab in Postman, but neither option has given me the result I wanted.

Postman Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run the same request in Postman as your screenshot shows (except using my sheet ID), with the same headers that you're using, my request succeeds. i.e., if you're sending the **Content-Type** header with value **application/json** for this request, you should not be receiving the error message that you're reporting (1124 - invalid content-type header).

You would, however, receive that error message if you were either not including the **Content-Type** header at all OR if you were specifying an invalid value for the **Content-Type** header.  A suggestion for troubleshooting:  use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) (or a similar tool) to examine the request that's being sent over the wire when you execute this request in Postman -- does it include the **Content-Type** header, and if so, what's the value of that header?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for adding a screenshot of the body you're setting in Postman -- I believe that's the source of your issue. i.e., your **Content-Type** header says that the request body is in JSON format, but you're actually not sending JSON. To fix this: instead of specifying key/value pairs in Postman, select the **raw** radio button and specify the body in JSON format. Here's a screenshot of what that looks like:

[image]

Comment: I attempted to examine the request with Fiddler and it appears it is sending the proper Content-Type header. Maybe I'm not reading it right, but it looks like I am including the header correctly.

Comment: I tried the same request as well, and it was also successful for me. @burnsa, what does the body of your request look like?

Comment: @stmcallister The body of my request looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/3qqqKnH.png).

Comment: @burnsa - I've updated my answer to include additional info. Please give that a try and if it resolves your issue, please mark this answer as "Accepted" so that others may benefit from it in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may forwarded from HTTP to HTTPS and content-type header will be missed

So make sure you make call to HTTPS end point.